# Laravel Homestead needs to access local web server

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, lotus-domino, homestead

I have the following setup in my DEV environment which is running on Windows 10 (which should be irrelevant).

- Homestead with Virtual box to develop my Laravel applications
- on my local OS I have a IBM Domino server running as dev1.mydomain.local

I'm trying to access the REST API on the Domino server from my Laravel installations. At the moment I'm getting 404 errors when trying because the domino server is not available from within the VirtualBox of Homestead.

Here is the network configuration of the homestead virtual box
  [image]

Both webservers Domino and nginx on the virtual box are running on standard ports

Here is the `ifconfig` output of the virtual box

[image]

How can I make that possible?

**UPDATE:**

It just came to me that I am able to access the Domino server with LDAP, so perhaps changing the http and https port of the Domino server is already the answer...

I will test that and then get back here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Port of the Domino server to 8080 enable me to access the server's REST API

```
dev1.mydomain.local:8080/api/data/
```

The connection to the local machine seems to be enable through the VirtualBox's second network adapter and the my call to the REST API got confused with the 2 web servers listening to the same port on localhost(127.0.0.1)

**Update**

although I was kind of able to connect to the server using the address above, still left me with the problem that authentication wasn't possible. In order to do so (and I have not the slightest idea why), I had to change to the local IP address of my PC to access the REST services

```
http://192.168.0.155:8080/api/data
```

If someone could explain that I would be happy :-)